# mysql not ignoring columns that are not in my sql query

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, mysql, manjaro

i am migrating from windows to manjaro linux but everything is fine but when i try to insert a query it's not ignoring the coloumns that are not in query but in table.
let's say i have table that store terms.
i have coloumns in that table - id, term_name, term_type, icon, sort_id

in windows if i use a query like

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO terms (term_name, term_type) VALUES ('some_name', 'category')";
```

`$query1` works in windows.

when i use $query1 in linux manjaro it does not work
it gives me error "field icon has no default value",

on my hostgator hosting $query1 works fine with no errors in logs.

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO terms (term_name, term_type, icon, sort_id) VALUES ('some_name', 'category', 'some_icon.png', 0)";
```

`$query2` query works in linux manjaro.

but now i cannot update so many queries to be as much absolute like this.

Comment: Did you re-create the database by hand or did you export it from Windows and import as SQL on Manjaro?

Comment: i exported from windows and imported in manjaro

Comment: 1) Do these columns have a default value if you check in phpMyAdmin or `show create table`? 2) Does the table structure look exactly the same on both Windows and Manjaro? 3) What MySQL or MariaDB version are you using on both systems?

Comment: no these coloumns have no default value, yes table structure is exactly same.
but the problem is i can't execute $query1 from phpmyadmin either , i get same error.
mysql version i seriously overlooked, i installed whatever was latest on that time when i installed xampp on windows.
-- Server version: 10.1.38-MariaDB  <- i found this version stamp in sql file i exported from windows

now in manjaro i installed lamp stack manually.
-- Server version: 10.4.6-MariaDB Source distribution <- i found this info from terminal in manjaro

Comment: If they have no default value, then I'd guess the new behavior is completely correct and curious why the _old_ system ignored those columns... Are those 'null' or 'not null' columns?

Comment: these are not null columns

Comment: So... if they're not-null and have no default value, what exactly is INSERT supposed to put in them?

Comment: nothing, it is supposed to be ignored, that's what was happening in windows and hostgator, why this different behaviour in manjaro.

Comment: It cannot be ignored. All rows have the same columns. Either it has a value or it has 'NULL' in it – and if it's configured to be "not null", it must have a value.

Comment: it's fine if those can't be ignored, but how those queries were working in windows and still working in windows but not in linux manjaro

Comment: i solved my problem, it was problem with sql strict mode.

Comment: Post it as an answer below for future reference.